# Can not open Pack Installer in keil microVison 5

Tags: keil

I have recently installed Keli microVision 5.I want to use STM32F401 as target target platform in Keil project. But it is not there by default. So I need to add it with Pack Installer. But I can not open it. Icon of Pack Installer is always gray.

When I installed Keil Pack Installer didn't opened by default, like I saw on YouTube videos, where Pack installer immediately opens after installation.

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem. Solved it by reinstalling Keil IDE, be careful when choosing installation folders: cause one for CORE, another for Packs, and they must be different.
(I think i've chosed same folder for CORE and Packs at first time and that caused this kind of problem)

Answer (score 0):

i faced this problem and the solution was simply that you need to install the MDK file not the CXX ones in the end of installing process the pack installer will prompt automatically